# Get Collection of Field Value in Client Side Rendering

Tags: 2013, client-side-rendering

I would like to get collection field value using CSR/JSLink.Below code is iterating value of the particular column.But,in my scenario i needed to get whole collection.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var arr = "";
    (function () {

            var overrideCtx = {};
            overrideCtx.Templates =  {};

            overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
                            'Title': { 'View' : CustomField }
         };

         SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);



    })();

    //alert(arr);

    function CustomField(ctx) {

        var currentValue=ctx.CurrentItem.Title;

        // arr+=currentValue;

        return currentValue;


    }

</script>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: You want get Field collection for particular list using jslink ?

Comment: Can you please clarify your needs? It is not clear right now

Answer (score 1):

All the fields are in an array of objects:

```
ctx.ListSchema.Field
```

All the rows are in

```
ctx.ListData.Row
```